# Build Lisp code in SublimeText2

Tags: macos, lisp, sublimetext

Any way to build&run common lisp in ST2 on mac os? I know about SLIME and Emacs, but i'm interested in ST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to install interpreter, in my case I used [sbcl](http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html).

After installing that it's prety simple.
On ST2 go to ***Preferences/Browse Packages***, go to Lisp, add a new file *Lisp.sublime-settings* with:

```
{
    "cmd": ["sbcl", "--script", "$file"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.lisp",
    "osx":
    {
        "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/sbcl", "--script", "$file"]
    },
    // exemple in windows with CLISP
    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["clisp", "$file"]
    }
    // exemple in windows with SBCL
    // "windows":
    // {
    //  "cmd": ["sbcl", "--script", "$file"]
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On windows, I was able to use the REPL by combining [GNU Common Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcl/gcl.html) and the package [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL).

Now, I don't know if it's possible on OSX, but I would be really surprised if it wasn't.

You'll have to add Lisp REPL to SublimeREPL, because it doesn't provide it by default, but it's pretty easy to configure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you want to program in Lisp on Mac you can also try using Clozure CL with its development environment:

http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter5.1.html#ccl-ide-introduction

I did not use it yet, but probably it is worth having a chance.

Comment: Please provide answers, when you know what you are talking about.